# Load text files on mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

I have to create a php script that allows to insert in a mysql database several text files that a user in an HTML page passes to him.
I found several examples on the internet of how to upload only one predefined text file, but none on how to upload several text files. The next code loads a predefined text file in a mysql database and it is the code that i will use to create the script of the problem :

```
    <?php
    if(($_POST["fileToUpload"])&&(["fileToUpload "]!=" ")){

 $variabile=$_POST["fileToUpload"];
 $server = "localhost";
 $nomeUtente = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "presenze";

 $connessione = mysqli_connect($server, $nomeUtente, $password, $database);
 if ($connessione->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connessione->connect_error);
}

$utenti=array();
$i=0;
    if ($file=fopen("utenti.txt","r"))
{
    while (!feof($file)){
        $riga=fgets($file,255);
        $riga=explode(",",$riga);
        $cf=$riga[0];
        $nome=$riga[1];
        $cognome=$riga[2];
        $telefono=$riga[3];


        $sql= "INSERT INTO personale (cf, nome, cognome, telefono) 
               VALUES ('$cf', '$nome',
              '$cognome', '$telefono')"; 




        $i++;//Incremento l'indice
        if ($connessione->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        } else {

            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connessione->error;
        }
    }   
    echo"<h3><br> Operazione completata!</h3>";


    fclose($file);
}
}
```

In the code there is an attempt to pass the text files from the html page, but it's just an attempt, the script works even without that piece, because directly loads the "utenti.txt" file. 
(p.s. sorry for my english, but i am not native speaker.)

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: How can i load different text files into database through an Html page that send a text file to php script and the php script load the text file into databse ?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Additionally, share your attempts - where **exactly** in the process are you stuck?